# Jquery and Radio button event after section get visible

Tags: jquery

This is my first time to post my query on stackoverflow. I have created one form and in the form have a drop down of few cities. On drop down change related group of radio button get displayed. Every radio button has same name as "preferred_location".

On any selection of radio button i want to mark one checkbox as CHECKED. I have tried lots of option available on net and they sound simple and work in demo but not in my code. To review i have posted my code sample here below:

Jquery script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#address input[name*='redio']").click(function() {
            $('#note').removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
        });  
    });
```

To display radio button group on change of dropdown i am using below code

```
if(valuecheckdrop == "Coimbatore"){ 
   $("#address").html("<h2>Select date of info session:</h2>",
       "<p>",
       "<input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='Radio1' class='redio' /> Radio1",
       "</p>",
       "<p class='sub'>address</p>",
       "<p class='option'>",
           "<input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='Radio2'  class='redio' />Radio2",
       "</p>",
       "<p class='sub'>Address2</p>");
}
```

On drop down change group of radio button get displayed but nothing is happen on click of radio button.

Is it because i am calling radio button on change event of drop down? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `input[name*='redio']` - use `input[type='radio']`

Comment: sorry but this also not working at my end.. I know its pretty easy but not finding reason why its not working at my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#graduate").change(function () {
                    var valuecheckdrop = $("#graduate").val();
                     $('#cbTest').prop('checked', false);
                    if (valuecheckdrop == "") {
                        $("#note").show();

                        //$("#address").removeClass("addresson").addClass("addressoff");
                        //Or
                        $("#address").html('');

                    } else {
                        $("#note").hide();

                        //$("#address").removeClass("addressoff").addClass('addresson');

                        switch (valuecheckdrop) {
                            case 'Bangalore':
                                $("#address").html("<h2>Select date of info session:</h2><p><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='June 2, 2012, Sat 11am - 1pm The Presidency, No. 1 St Marks Road' class='redio' /> June 2, 2012 <span>(Sat 11am - 1pm)</span></p><p class='sub'>The Presidency, No. 1 St Marks Road</p><p class='option'><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='June 2, 2012, Sat 3pm - 5pm Manipal Center, Dickenson Road' class='redio' /> June 2, 2012 <span>(Sat 3pm - 5pm)</span></p><p class='sub'>Manipal Center, Dickenson Road</p><p class='option'><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='June 3, 2012, Sun 12noon - 5pm Taj Gateway Hotel, Residency Road' class='redio' />June 3, 2012 <span>(Sun 12noon - 5pm)</span></p><p class='sub'>Taj Gateway Hotel, Residency Road</p><p class='option'><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='June 4, 2012, Mon 11am - 1pm S&B Towers, MG Road' class='redio' />June 4, 2012 <span>(Mon 11am - 1pm)</span></p><p class='sub'>S&B Towers, MG Road</p>");
                                break;
                            case 'Chandigarh':
                                $("#address").html("<h2>Select date of info session:</h2><p><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='May 26, 2012, Sat 10:30am - 5:30pm The Park Hote, Anna Salai' class='redio' /> May 26, 2012 <span>(Sat 10:30am - 5:30pm)</span></p><p class='sub'>The Park Hote, Anna Salai</p><p class='option'><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='May 28, 2012, Mon 1pm - 3pm No. 16, Nungambakkam' class='redio' />May 28, 2012<span>(Mon 1pm - 3pm)</span></p><p class='sub'>No. 16, Nungambakkam</p><p class='option'><input type='radio' name='preferred_location' value='May 28, 2012, Mon 10am - 12noon Sindur Shopping Centre, Anna Nagar' class='redio' /> May 28, 2012 <span>(Mon 10am - 12noon)</span></p><p class='sub'>Sindur Shopping Centre, Anna Nagar</p>");
                                break;
                        }

                        //$("#address").find(':radio:first').prop('checked', true);
                    }
                });

                $("#graduate").trigger('change');

                $("#address").find(':radio').live('click', function (e) {
                    $('#cbTest').prop('checked', $("#address").find(':radio:checked').length > 0);
                });
            });​
```

Comment: add class="CommonCityRadio" for every radio button and check this code. can u add u r html and jquery in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks for your reply ThulasiRam. I have made changes as per my requirement but it not working at my end.Please check below updated code  $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#address input[name*='preferred_location']").click(function() {
        $("#address input[type='radio']").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            $('#note').removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
        });  
    });

Comment: Hi TulasiRam please find link of my code http://jsfiddle.net/9J6qR/2/  on radio button check box should get checked. any idea how can i get the result i want

Comment: what u need can u expline me step by step example?

Comment: On change of drop down a bunch of different locations of radio button get visual. However this is working fine. I want checkbox must get CHECKED on any one of radio button selection. Hope you got my requirement.

Comment: You will find Checkbox just above the drop down box. i have added break now. here is listed link of code http://jsfiddle.net/9J6qR/2/

Comment: TulasiRam thank you very much for all your support. Its working as i want. Thank you very very much..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#address input[name*='radio']").on('click',function() {
        $('#note').removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Priyank tried your provided code but not working for me. Really want to find out why this small think is not working. BTW thank for your reply.